# ListView from remote database onItemClickListener not passing position integer

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio

I have looked at other SO questions and didn't find one that approached my specific issue. If I missed one, I apologize.

I have a listview from a remote database. If the user clicks on an item, I want the items information to pass over to a detail activity with more information loaded. When I ran the app and clicked on an item the logcat said "Integer cannot be cast to RowData". From what I've researched online and what I'm used to using within Eclipse I assumed getting the item's position would work. I am using Android Studio with Volley. Here's my onItemClickListener and my RowData class:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //Get item at position
            RowData item = (RowData) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

            //Pass the image title and url to DetailsActivity
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("title", item.getTitle());
            intent.putExtra("image", item.getImageURL());

            //Start details activity
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

RowData:

```
public class RowData {
private String demo_name;
private String demo_size;
private String demo_image;
private String demo_detail;
private String demo_region;
public RowData(String demo_name,String demo_size,String demo_image,String demo_detail,String demo_region){
    this.demo_name=demo_name;
    this.demo_size=demo_size;
    this.demo_image=demo_image;
    this.demo_detail=demo_detail;
    this.demo_region=demo_region;

    }

    public String getTitle(){
        return demo_name;

    }
    public String getDescription(){
        return demo_size;

    }
    public String getImageURL(){
        return demo_image;

    }
    public String getDetailURL(){
        return demo_detail;
    }
    public String getRegionURL(){
        return demo_region;
    }
}
```

CustomAdapter:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{
private ArrayList<RowData> result;
private ArrayList<RowData> orig;
private Context context;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public CustomAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, ArrayList<RowData> data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    result=data;
    context=mainActivity;

    inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
            getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return result.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            final FilterResults oReturn = new FilterResults();
            final ArrayList<RowData> results = new ArrayList<RowData>();
            if (orig == null)
                orig = result;
            if (constraint != null) {
                if (orig != null && orig.size() > 0) {
                    for (final RowData g : orig) {
                        if (g.getTitle().toLowerCase()
                                .contains(constraint.toString()))
                            results.add(g);
                    }
                }
                oReturn.values = results;
            }
            return oReturn;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                      FilterResults results) {
            result = (ArrayList<RowData>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}

public class Holder
{
    TextView title;
    TextView description;
    NetworkImageView img;
}
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Holder holder=new Holder();
    View rowView;
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    holder.title=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    holder.description=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    holder.img=(NetworkImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.networkImageView);
    holder.title.setText(result.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.description.setText(result.get(position).getDescription());

    // If you are using NetworkImageView
    holder.img.setImageUrl(result.get(position).getImageURL(), VolleyController.getInstance().getImageLoader());

    return rowView;
}
}
```

Comment: use arraylist instead of parent to get item at required position

Comment: Please add full logcat error trace.

Comment: Can you post your adapter code as well? I think the problem is somewhere in your `getItemAtPosition()`method. It would be great if we can see your adapter's `getItem()` method that get's called internally.

Comment: @DanailAlexiev added adapter code

Comment: @SteveC. You can check out my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}
```

You should override this method, so it return the `RowData` object in the specified position. Something like:

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    if (result == null) {
        return null;
    }

    return result.get(position);
}
```

Your original representation was returning and `int`, which you tried casting to `RowData` and this was causing the crash.

Comment: Ok. Your method works but it's not passing the image to the detail activity. I have this for the image: imageView = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.detailImageView);

Comment: @SteveC. In order to solve this, I'll probably need to see your `DetailActivity ` code. Things you can do to solve it yourself: verify, that the image URL is not null, verify it is correctly passed to the details activity, verify you are calling `setImageUrl()` on your `NetworkImageView` and, lastly, verify that the image actually exists.

Comment: lol I feel like an idiot. I figured it out. I forgot to set the image url. Can't believe I didn't see that. I must be tired. I appreciate your help. You solved my problem of getting the data over. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

`getItem()` is supposed to return the item at that position, but you are returning the position itself. That's why you are getting an integer where you should have gotten `RowData`

Change

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}
```

to

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return result.get(position);
}
```